How to create type T and value of type T template with default type T?
As question says. I'd like to create a template, e.g. of class, that takes in typename T and T val as parameters, in which I can specify default T type.
I tried this:
template <typename T = int, T V = 0>
class Example
{

};

Example<int, 1> a; // compiles
Example<int> a; // compiles
Example a; // compiles
Example<1> a; // Error: "expected type specifier"

but the one thing I would like to work does not.
How can I do this right?

How about template specialization? Or perhaps just type aliases?

my bad. to litlle code coppied

immediate -1 for profanities

@3CxEZiVlQ added necessary code

OT: Instead of template <typename T = int, T V = 0> do template <typename T = int, T V = T{}>. That way, any default-constructible type T can be used, not only those with compile-time constant conversion from int (or any pointer).

You are trying to pass an integer literal 1 where a typename is expected. That obviously will not work.
Unfortunately, partial template specialization will not work, either:
template <typename T = int, T V = T{}>
class Example
{
};

template <int N>
class Example<int, N>
{
};

/* alternatively:

template<auto T>
class Example<decltype(T), T>
{

};

*/

Example<int, 1> a; // compiles
Example<int> a; // compiles
Example a; // compiles
Example<1> a; // Error

But, a type alias will work:
template <typename T = int, T V = T{}>
class Example
{
};

template <int N>
using Example_int = Example<int, N>;

Example<int, 1> a; // compiles
Example<int> a; // compiles
Example a; // compiles
Example_int<1> a; // compiles


It's impossible to support this exact syntax (all 4 forms at the same time).
The closest thing I can think of is:
template <auto V = 0>
struct Example {};

Example<int(1)> a; // Type and value.
Example<int{}> a;  // Type only.
Example a;         // Neither.
Example<1> a;      // Value only.


I care mostly about the last one
